# Python: Find all pairwise distances between points and return points along with distance

Tags: list, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a list containing list of points with a name and coordinates in 3D. Something like this with a **much larger length of the list**:

```
group=[[gr1, 5, 8, 9], [gr2, 7, 4, 5], [gr3, 3, 8, 1], [gr4, 3, 4, 8]]
```

I want to calculate **all possible pairwise distances** among the coordinates and return the **distance along with the corresponding points.** Something like this:

```
distances=[[gr1, gr2, 6.],[gr1, gr3, 8.24621125], [gr1, gr4, 4.58257569], [gr2, gr3, 6.92820323], [gr2, gr4, 5.], [gr3, gr4, 8.06225775]]
```

I tried using scipy.spatial.distance.pdist but that only returns me this

```
array([ 6.        ,  8.24621125,  4.58257569,  6.92820323,  5.        ,
    8.06225775])
```

How do I **extract the information along with the groups that were considered for each distance value**?

I am a beginner and I am using python 3. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try two nested for-loops to combine every element in "group" except the last one with every other element to the right:

```
group=[["gr1", 5, 8, 9], ["gr2", 7, 4, 5], ["gr3", 3, 8, 1], ["gr4", 3, 4, 8]]

distances=[]

for i,g in enumerate(group[:-1]):
    for h in group[i+1:]:
        d = ((g[1]-h[1])**2+(g[2]-h[2])**2+(g[3]-h[3])**2)**0.5
        distances.append([g[0],h[0],d])

print(*distances,sep="\n")
```

Result:

```
['gr1', 'gr2', 6.0]
['gr1', 'gr3', 8.246211251235321]
['gr1', 'gr4', 4.58257569495584]
['gr2', 'gr3', 6.928203230275509]
['gr2', 'gr4', 5.0]
['gr3', 'gr4', 8.06225774829855]
```